# Is it possible to define iron-router server side routes that respond to certain HTTP actions?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a basic server side route defined in iron-router like:

```
this.route('foo', {
  where: 'server',
  path: '/foo',
  action: function() {
    // handle response
  }
});
```

This appears to respond to a request at "/foo" with any HTTP action, i.e. a GET to "/foo" and a POST to "/foo" both trigger this route.

1. Is it possible to limit the response to a GET action, and let the
   other actions be notFound?
2. Similarly, is it possible to have a GET
   to "/foo" handled by one route, and a POST to "/foo" handled by another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely check the method and only respond if it's the one you want, e.g., like this:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('route', {
        path: '/mypath',
        where: 'server',
        action: function() {
            if (this.request.method != 'GET') {
                // do whatever
            } else {
                this.response.writeHead(404);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The second question beats me. It might be possible to use `this.next()` somehow, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sounds like at this point there's no built-in support for any of this so rolling it by hand like in this example is the best solution.