# POST request with redirect to Meteor

Tags: redirect, post, meteor

I'm looking to transfer a lot of information from one domain A to a meteor domain B when someone clicks a link on A. I was doing this before with GET params, but since there is a limit on the length of the URL, this doesn't work for large amounts of data. Submitting a form might be a solution, but I can't find a good client-side way of Meteor to parse POST data. LocalStorage would be a good option but it is inaccessible across different domains.

Seems like there should be a straightforward way to do this -- what am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to do this on the client side?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a server-side routing solution that can handle POSTs. If so, this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943084/is-it-possible-to-define-iron-router-server-side-routes-that-respond-to-certain/20943328#20943328

Comment: I need to render the client side templates as well, though. This should be the same as submitting a form (and getting POST data), but the target site is not the same site.